# Post image to inastagram from own android application

Tags: android, instagram

I have done Instagram integration in my own app. Now i want to upload photo from my app to Instsgram.

Comment: I have to say, the quality of questions this afternoon is quite something....

Comment: If you can integrate Instagram, you should know how to deal with photo upload.

Comment: Mitch, I am poor in English. Shivan, I am new to do this type of integration and all so hope some one help me.. but anyways thank you for replying.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your English: It's the question that is poor.

Comment: Mitch, have you integrated facebook , linkedin, g+ to any app?